# Waiting for a Key While Program is Opening in VB

Tags: vb.net

(I am a new person in stackoverflow, might ask a bit different)

**How to wait a key while launching a program?**

*VS2019 Visual Basic*

Hello, my program has a starting screen to load items. I want to make it so in start before loading anything wait for 2 seconds, waiting for a combination. If no combination used start it normaly, but if user presses F5(kust maked up) the program start on developer mode. How to do that?

I have no idea about have to do this, so I can't show any code?

Comment: You can start a 2 seconds timer and wait for it to finish while listening for keyboard inputs. How good are you with vb.net?

Comment: Where is the key coming from? Who asks for the key? Is the user providing the key? What do you mean by "developer mode"? What is "kust maked up"?

Comment: Sorry it's "just made up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a timer from Tool Box  (assume `Timer1` with Interval of `2` seconds for clarity purposes). Double click on the tray of that timer located at the bottom of the Form Designer.

Now, we may consider the following code:

Declaration:

```
Dim waitEnd As Boolean = True
```

Main code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If waitEnd Then ' if True
        waitEnd = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, suppose you want to work for key press wait with `SplashForm` named form. Go to its properties located at the bottom-right corner in VS, double-click on `KeyDown` event and then you may use the following steps:

```
Private Sub SplashForm_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Form1.KeyDown
    If waitEnd Then ' when waitEnd is True
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
            EnableYourMode()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps you to understand.